# Depth First Search in Parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, depth-first-search

I have a huge binary Tree (each Node has a Pass and Fail Node) and I want to traverse this Tree in order to get all possible Paths using DFS. Since the tree is huge, the time taken to DFS using a single thread is taking very long time. So in order to solve this problem, I am now considering doing parallel DFS. The basic idea is below.

- Start with a single thread and do a normal DFS, as this hits a node, spawn a new thread that start with the fail node as the start node and pass to that call the Node travelled so far
- The initial thread continues in the path of the pass
- At the end every thread will return a list of node that it has travelled; as such I would have traversed the whole Tree with multiple Thread. Since the so called Parent Thread passes information of the node it has travelled to the child Thread, each thread is so called Self-Sufficient

In order to implement this, I am thinking of doing this

- Use newCachedThreadPool.
- In the Main, I will create the Pool, and initiate a initial call to the Callable DFS Class. The constructor of the DFS class will also take the ExecutorService so that the newly spawned Thread can also spawn new Thread using the rule as discussed above

**Code Implementation of DFS**

```
    public class DFS implements Callable<List<List<TestNode>>> {
        private Node node = null;
        private List<TestNode> testNodeList = new ArrayList<TestNode>();
        private List<List<TestNode>> returnNodeList = new ArrayList<List<TestNode>>();
        private ExecutorService service = null;

        public DFS(ExecutorService service, Node node, List<TestNode> initList) {
           this.node = node;
           this.service = service;
           if (initList != null && initList.size() > 0) {
              testNodeList.addAll(initList);
        }
    }

    public List<List<TestNode>> call() throws Exception {
         performDFS(this.node);
         returnNodeList.add(testNodeList);
         return returnNodeList;
    }

    private void performDFS(Node node) {
         TestNode testNode = new TestNode();
         testNode.setName(node.getName());
         Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
         testNode.setThreadName(t.getName());
         testNodeList.add(testNode);

         if (node.getPass() != null) {
            performDFS(node.getPass());
         }
         if (node.getFail() != null) {
             Callable<List<List<TestNode>>> task = new DFS(service, node.getFail(),         
             this.testNodeList);
             Future<List<List<TestNode>>> returnList = service.submit(task);
             try {
                 returnNodeList.addAll(returnList.get());
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e) {
             }
             catch (ExecutionException e) {
             }
       }
    }
```

}

**Main Class**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
          Main main = new Main();
          Node root = main.createTree();
          ExecutorService service = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
          Callable<List<List<TestNode>>> task = new DFS(service, root, null);

          Future<List<List<TestNode>>> returnList = null;
          try {
             returnList = service.submit(task);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
         }
         try {
            main.displayTestNode(returnList.get());
            service.shutdown();
         }
         catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        catch (ExecutionException e) {
      }
   }
```

**Questions**

- Does this make sense? Is this even possible?
- There is problem with the implementation, as I can see the same Thread again and again

Comment: Unless your tree is perfectly balanced, or unless you already know a lot about your tree before you traverse it, then there is no guarantee you will get any speedup from parallelizing your DFS at the traversal level.  An extreme example is if your tree degenerates to become a linked list.  If it takes a long time to *process* each node, I suggest you parallelize each of the node processing tasks.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: the balancing argument is only true for a naive parallel algorithm. When each node's traversal is considered a separate task, it also works for unbalanced trees.

Comment: @larsmans: Which is what I was suggesting he do.  However if there is no processing for each task, then the overhead of creating the tasks is probably going to do more harm than good.  That is unless he somehow batches up large chunks of the tree.  The problem: How do you tell how large a chunk of the tree is without traversing it?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the Tree so until I traverse the full tree, I know nothing. The main reason for doing this is because I want to create a so called Control Flow Graph(CFG) out of it. When I traverse the tree, there might be path that are common, which I will refactor later. The first step of doing that, I think is to first understand the tree and that can only be done if I traverse the whole tree

Comment: I think you should first do a breadth-first scan in order to locate 4 (or some other small number) independent subtrees and then divide that work between that many threads, with no further forking. But then, if your tree is unbalanced, this will not be as efficient as it might be and you may need work-stealing to get the most out of it. That would imply ForkJoin.

Comment: How long does it take to process a node vs traversing to the node?  If processing a node takes much longer, then you need not worry about trying to do a parallel *traversal* at all.  Please profile this, or demonstrate why your processing of each node takes negligible time with respect to traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to write a parallel DFS. It might also be possible using thread pools, but a [fork/join](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/papers/fj.pdf)-style algorithm would I think be more "natural". The fork operation would traverse all children of a node in parallel, while the join operation would simply concatenate the lists of paths returned.

Comment: Good suggestion, Let me explore that area also

Comment: Looks like not the solution as I am using Java 6

Answer (score -1):

Well, I think the biggest problem with this is that multithreading won't help you, since you never execute anything in parallel. You spawn one thread, then immediately wait, so only one thread can be computing anything at one moment.

Another question to ask would be why (and if) you want the list of all paths at all. In a tree, paths from the root are uniquely identified by their endpoint (and can be reconstructed from there by following the "up" links). Moreover, the list of all paths has bigger memory complexity (in a full balanced binary tree with `N` nodes, the memory complexity of the tree is `O(N)`, whereas the memory complexity of the list of all paths would be `O(N*log(N))`, which would be the time complexity of its creation, too). Even if the "up" links are not provided in a tree, you can just reconstruct them (maybe as an `IdentitiyHashMap<Node, Node>`) in `O(N)` time, which will take you less time (and memory!) than constructing the list of all paths. I really don't think you should begin processing large trees by converting them to a wasteful representation.

Comment: If they have no "up" links, then you must construct the path to the leaf while traversing to it.

Comment: I answered your question in the other comment

Comment: @jpalecek: You're pretty quick to say "wrong", which implies nothing I said was correct.  So the point I was trying to make was that if you don't have anything but down-links, then you have to traverse the tree to get paths, and what you wrote before implied that up-links would always exist.  Your solution for storing the paths (as an up-link map) is definitely a valid one.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Okay, I was interpreting your statement in the context of the OP's question, which implied constructing the paths equals creating `ArrayList`s. Of course, it could be interpreted more broadly as the need for some preprocessing, and the way proposed by me is by no means the only one, but that interpretation didn't seem obvious in the context of this question (noone mentioned anything similar). That's why I objected to your "if ... you *must* ..." sentence.

Comment: Just to clarify, in this context I do not have any uplinks, the only way to traverse the tree is through the child nodes (Pass and Fail) Node.