# Making a Depth first-search algorithm in java

Tags: java, depth-first-search

I have the following directed graph implementation

```
 Nodes nod[]
 List<Arcs> arc[]
```

So the node on the n'th position has all his arcs of the list in position n. Of course, the nodes are organized accordingly, so that I can use Binary Search. 
Based on this implementation. I wish to create a DFS algorithm. I know very well the pseudo code, adapting to java shouldn't be a problem.

But my question is the following. In DFS we need to start searching from the "top" node. And thinking about it, i dont have this "top" node. Moreover, I have no idea how to get it.
So I ask, how do i get this top node, considering my implementation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: So are all the Nodes in the array considered top level nodes?

Comment: Refer this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10258204/depth-first-search-in-parallel

Comment: @Brad No no. Thats the problem. Its a normal graph. And i need to find the top node

Comment: @RahulTripathi Not really answering my question.

Comment: Assuming that the root node is not in a known position (first, middle, whatever) I suppose you'd have to look for the node that doesn't have an arc going *to* it.

Comment: @beaker agreed. Write up some sudo code so you can get credit for the answer

Comment: @beaker that's not necessary, the generic algorithm tries to do DFS starting from every node, so there are as many iterations as nodes in the graph. On the other hand, if the graph is connected, one single iteration is enough to mark all nodes as "visited", so all remaining iterations will do nothing

Comment: it takes `O(n^2)` time if we test every node for all adjacent edges being incoming

Comment: @mangusta We'll call it `O(E)` since we're using an adjacency list. And no, it's not necessary, but if the number of "top" nodes is small, this approach will avoid situations where a descendent node is chosen before its ancestor. Remember, the graph is directed, so there may not necessarily be a path from node a to node b.

Comment: @beaker we still have to mark all nodes as "visited", that's the point of DFS, so i guess there's no difference if we choose a child node before its ancestor or after. there will be one more iteration but complexity still stays O(E+V)

Comment: @mangusta I guess that depends on the order of the traversal you want. In the simple case of `A->B->C`, would you want an order `A, B, C` or `C, B, A`? Either one is valid in the scenario you propose. The OP seemed to want the first.

Comment: @mangusta See the other answer below and the OP's comment regarding it.

Comment: @beaker hm, don't know what OP means by "top" node. is it a node that has a least number of incoming edges?

Comment: @mangusta I took it to mean a node with **no** incoming edges, and the code in my answer reflects that. I looked at it as series of trees with distinct roots, possibly with common descendants, but each descendant would appear in only one DFS tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment:

Assuming that the arcs are directed (i.e., from the parent node to the child only) you can search all of the nodes for the one with no incoming arcs:

```
// parent_count is an integer array of the same size as nod[]

for i = 1..n
    for each arc in arc[i] (arc going from i to j)
        increment parent_count[j]
    end
end

for k = 1..n
    if parent_count[k] == 0
        return k
end
```

Answer (score 0):

DFS/BFS are very common and general algorithms to travel over the graph, both has no special meaning of top node, you could start DFS from any node. For example, DFS is used in topological sort algorithm and it states that we have to start from nodes with no incoming edges.

Could you please highlight what problem you want to solve? This should help us to find nodes that has to be used as a roots for DFS.

Comment: yes you are correct. You can choose any node and DFS will search. But in this particular case i want to start searching from the top node for particular reason. Still i was given a solution how to find the top node.